# Does 切った mean to "cut out" or "cut from"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, jlpt

I was pretty sure that `切{き}った` meant something was cut *from* something else. So `ケーキから一人分{ひっとりぶん}を切{き}った` would mean, "one piece was cut from the cake."

However, I came across a usage which, at least at first, doesn't seem to conform to that understanding. In my JLPT textbook, there is this graph showing the number of people in the farming industry *(ignore the red line, it's just a pen mark)*:

[image: jlpt graph]

One question asked which of four sentences best describes the change from the beginning to the end of the graph. This is the correct answer:

> 一千{いっせん}万人{まんにん}を上回{うわまわ}っていたものが、300万{まん}人{にん}を切{き}った。

My erroneous interpretation was that the sentence meant something like "There were over 10 million people, but 3 million were cut." Or, in other words, 3 million cut from 10 million leaves 7 million remaining. But the graph shows it's 3 million remaining, not 7 million, so I didn't think this was the right answer.

Instead, after checking the answers and seeing that this sentence is indeed the correct description, I'm now guessing the sentence is supposed to mean "There were over 10 million people, but it was **cut down to** 3 million."

However, I can't see how in this sentence `切{き}った` means "cut down to", and not "cut from".

What is it that I am not seeing in this sentence, or what am I not understanding about `切{き}る`?

Comment: (I know this is off-topic but I think we'd say more like ケーキを[一切れ]{ひときれ}・[一人分]{ひとりぶん}切った than [一分]{いちぶ}.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just because one of the figurative meanings of "cut" in English is "to reduce in number", doesn't mean that the same applies to 切る in Japanese. That is simply not one of the figurative meanings of 切る.

切るdoes have many figurative meanings, however.

One is "fall below" for prices, times, numbers etc.

Another is to "lay off, fire". When used in this sense, the meaning might seem close to "to reduce in number", so that could be one cause for the confusion.

Comment: I'm on board with the idea that 切る doesn't correlate directly with cut. The only reason I'm finding it hard to wrap my head around it is two reasons. One is that all my dictionaries don't show any meaning like "fall below". For example, [Space ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%88%87%E3%82%8B&ref=sa). The other reason is that in all the years I've been in Japan, I've never encountered this variant of 切る before. Again, I'm not trying to deny it means what you say, just that it's strange to me how it works. "Cut to" and "cut from" are opposing concepts, so how can the same word do both?

Comment: How about if you visualize it as a line on a graph "cutting" through another line as it goes down?

Comment: @Matt Yes, I think that's how I grasp the word, it's like cutting 10 seconds into 9.9 + 0.1, cutting 10,000 yen into 9,980 yen + 20 yen, cos you can also rephrase this '切る' as '割る'

Comment: On Space ALC, the first relevant definition if you just search for 切る is probably:
 break《ゴルフ》（スコアがあるポイントを)

But that only works if you know what "break 100" means in a golf context. Although you also see this used in other sporting contexts, e.g. "break the four minute mile".

Comment: @DaveMG ""Cut to" and "cut from" are opposing concepts, so how can the same word do both?" Doesn't "cut" do them both in English? It does in your formulations.

Comment: @dainichi: Yeah, it does. Doh! :) That occured to me a little later and you see me coming that realization in my second comment on SomethingJapanese's answer. So I think I'm closer to grasping it, but the part I'm still pondering is whether or not it's always true that in Japanese, the default focus is on the remainder, as opposed to English where the default focus is on the amount removed.

Comment: @DaveMG Thinking about it some more, I think you might actually be onto something. If you want to focus on the thing you're cutting away, you might use 切り取る or 切り離す. As you say 切る probably focuses on thing you're cutting *into* by default (not necessarily the remainder).

Comment: @dainichi: Could you explain more about what you mean by focusing the thing you're "cutting into" as opposed focusing on the remainder? I'm a little unclear on how that would work.

Comment: @DaveMG Well, I think it's hard to find logic that covers all figurative meanings of "cut" and 切る, since there will most probably be exceptions. I'm just saying that maybe by default, the object of 切る will no longer be intact. So you might say that 300万人を切った means that the 3mio chunk of people in agriculture is no longer "intact", i.e. no longer whole. With "cut", this doesn't seem to be as strict, you can "cut a piece from the cake", but "the piece" is not really what you're cutting into, you're cutting into "the cake" and *removing* a piece.

Comment: @DaveMG Cont'd: This might also explain why ケーキから一人分を切る doesn't sound quite as correct to me as ケーキから一人分を切り取る, since you're not really cutting into the slice, but into the cake. 切り取る and e.g. 切り離す don't have the same semantic restriction, they don't really mean "cutting (into)" something, they mean "separating by cutting", and what you're cutting could be something else (than the direct object).

Comment: @dainichi: I think it's coming together now. While I understand that one can never encompass all exceptions, it seems that 切る refers fairly strictly to the act of separation (like the English "cut"), and then the *default*, but not always, assumption in Japanese is to refer to the remainder (unlike the English, which focuses on the part deleted or removed). If you think that's more or less right, then I'd mark this answer as correct (I'll leave it up to you if you want to make the answer more reflective of this conversation, or just leave it in the comments).

Answer (score 8):

This 切{き}る means 下回{したまわ}る, to fall below~~.

Comment: I'm totally unfamiliar with this definition of 切る. It's also not coming up in my dictionaries. Is this a common usage?

Comment: Yes, I think it's quite common, and I think it's a bit more conversational than 下回る. My smaller Japanese dictionary (岩波国語辞典) says "切る②㋓《助詞「を」を介し、値段・量などの基準を示す語と合して》下回る。割る。「原価を切って売る」「10秒を切る」". One of my Japanese-English dictionaries says "切る--④[下回る]100メートル競走に10秒を切った He broke the 10 second mark in the 100-meter race. かばんを元値を切って売っている They are selling the bags below costs."

Comment: It's very common for falling prices: 「20インチ液晶モニターが一万円を切った」

Comment: Okay, but now I'm wondering how can I know it means "cut from" or "cut down to". What is there about the sentence in my question that makes my initial translation wrong?

Comment: Hmm I think it depends on the context, but if it means "下回る/割る" then there should be at least a phrase showing a price/number/amount + the case particle を just before it.

Comment: In your first sentence, "from" comes from から, not from 切る.

Comment: @PaulRichter: I would translate that is there being 10,000 yen off the price. Is it supposed to mean that the price has been reduced to 10,000 yen?

Comment: @DaveMG No, it means that it has *fallen below* 10,000 yen.

Answer (score 4):

Don't think about "cut".  Stop thinking about "cut from" or "cut down to" or anything else.  At a certain point, thinking in English about Japanese becomes more obstructive than anything else.  Just think in Japanese.

Well, OK, the example from your question (300万まん人にんを切きった。) isn't the most intuitive.  Let's go with another example.  I first encountered this meaning in the context of a race, and I think that's a great way to understand this meaning, so we'll go with that (lifting Chocolate's example from another comment...).  Again, only think in Japanese.

> 100メートル競走{きょうそう}に10秒{びょう}を切{き}った。

この文だけに集中して、想像して。この人は毎日１００メートル走を走っている。毎日走って、毎日１０秒以上のタイムしか取れない。そこで、ある日この人は本当に思い切って走って、なんと！タイムは９.９秒！この人はやっと１０秒を切った！。。。という。

...Once you've got a good grasp on this sense of 切る in one setting, you can easily carry that over to other settings.

I hope that helps at all. =X  (If I made mistakes, by all means point them out, fix them!)

Comment: This is a very informative answer... except that I'm not sure that "thinking in English" is really the problem here. I have a definition in my head for 切る, but it's not that it's an English definition, it's just the definition I have. I'm only using English as one way of expressing that definition here on this site, because I don't have the Japanese ability to express my definitions in Japanese. So, I guess what I'm saying is, don't mistake talking about Japanese words in English with defining Japanese words in English. Other than that, though, a helpful answer. +1 :)

Comment: @Dave M G: Well, the main idea (not explicitly stated in the answer) is, discard your preconceptions - in whatever language - as much as possible and just focus on what's in the sentence, and what doesn't make sense in that sentence, and how to make it make sense.

I actually kind of think of this meaning of 切る like breaking a wall, perhaps with some *sharp*, decisive (cutting?) action.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see it now. 切る is just "cut", not "cut to" or "cut from". Whether not something is cut "to" or "from" comes from the grammar around it. Which is like English, now that I think of it. But, unlike English, the default assumption of whether to focus on the remainder or the source after the cutting is done might be opposite. In any case, to test if I've got this right, would it be grammatical to say 「1000メートル競走に10秒が切きった」 to mean I cut ten seconds **off** my time? Or would it have to be 「1000メートル競走に10秒から切きった」?

Comment: I'm not sure I actually see that meaning in [切る](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%88%87%E3%82%8B)'s definition.  The [JE entry](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%88%87%E3%82%8B) includes "reduce/decrease/discount", but I'm not sure what Japanese definition that's supposed to fit, so I don't trust that it's the same as what you're trying to say here.  I'd feel much more comfortable using 削{けず}る.  Maybe a native speaker can give you a more confident answer.

Comment: EDIT it won't let me do to the previous...[goo](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/58524/m0u/%E5%88%87%E3%82%8B/) actually says 「元値を―・って売る」, or "discount" it seems, but I still don't know how to use that well enough to confidently tell you how to say what you want to (supposing you can).

Comment: 元値を切って売る is still the "fall below" interpretation. You're selling at a price (which has fallen) below the original price.

Comment: @DaveMG 10秒が切った and 10秒から切った don't work since the 10 seconds aren't doing the cutting, nor is anything cut from the 10 seconds. Logically, it would be *1000メートル競走(の記録)から10秒切った, but as SomethingJapanese says, 削る is used here: 1000メートル競走(の記録)から10秒削った.